# Do I have to call py::initialize_interpreter() and py::finalize_interpreter() within the same scope?

Tags: python, c++, cpython, pybind11

I am trying to embed Python script in my C++ application.
I am wondering if I have to call `py::initialize_interpreter()` and `py::finalize_interpreter()` within the same scope, like below.

```
if(condition){
   py::initialize_interpreter();
   {
       other pybind processes
   }
   py::finalize_interpreter();
}
```

Or can I do something like：

```
if(condition){
   py::initialize_interpreter();
}
 /*** other C++ code***/

if(condition){
   other pybind processes
}

/*** other C++ code***/
if(condition){
   py::finalize_interpreter();
}
```

Is this going to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need to call it in same scope, however you need to be aware that you can **not** call the `py::initialize_interpreter();` again once it was initialized. To call it again you first need to call `py::finalize_interpreter();`.